# Migrate Ember app from bower to npm

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower

As I understand Ember Team recommended to migrate applications from bower to npm, but I wasn't able to find clear migration plan for that. Does someone have successful migration experience? Could you please share your experience or give some useful links with detailed instructions. Thanks.

this is my current bower.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "ember": "^2.14.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.3.5",
    "inputmask": "~3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-star-rating": "~3.5.2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.5.0",
    "pubnub": "3.15.2",
    "bootstrap-switch": "^3.3.2",
    "soundmanager2": "*",
    "lodash": "^2.4.0",
    "mixpanel": "~2.7.1",
    "slick-carousel": "1.5.8",
    "seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "~6.0.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "ember": "2.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: This depends on your dependencies. Ember itself does not need bower anymore. But you don't have to do much for that. Just go with `ember init`.

Comment: Is this an Ember CLI application? Did you try the instructions at https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2017/01/23/ember-2-11-released.html#toc_upgrading-ember-cli or https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.11.0 ?

Comment: yes, this is ember cli application 2.14. and I would like to get clear instructions of how to migrate my existing Bower dependencies from bower.json to npm project.json file and finally remove bower.json at all.

Answer (score 1):

To switch to Ember from npm you need to include `ember-source` in your `package.json` file as shown here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/f98da31d2299050773c98e01b1019437cd323391/package.json

You no longer need a bower.json file, so the only things in it should be addoms that you haven't yet migrated to npm equivalents ...

Comment: I currently have several imports in my ember-cli-build.js
like:
...
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-star-rating/js/star-rating.js');
    app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-star-rating/css/star-rating.css');

    app.import('bower_components/pubnub/web/dist/pubnub.js');

    app.import('bower_components/soundmanager2/script/soundmanager2.js');
    app.import('bower_components/soundmanager2/swf/soundmanager2.swf', {destDir: 'swf'});
...
Do I understand you correctly that you suggested me to find Addons for all bower packages I currently have and use in ember-cli-build.js ?

Comment: Yes. The long-term trajectory in Ember is to remove Bower usage, as it is hard to do tree-shaking and other advanced build steps when using Bower libraries. It isn't a requirement yet, but I would not be surprised if at some point Bower usage was more expressly discouraged. Already, most popular addon are busy removing their need for it ...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion. Can you also suggest what should developers do in case there is no Addon for bower package they currently use? How can I add to my vendor.css and vendor.js styles and script I'm currently use with bower. How can I move to dest folder some swf file like soundmanager2‌​.swf? I'm asking because I currently can't use import() with node_modules folder.

Comment: Take a look at https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation; it should answer a few of your questions.

Comment: In the now-released version of Ember-CLI 2.15, it's possible to do an `app.import()` from the `node_modules` folder (https://emberjs.com/blog/2017/09/01/ember-2-15-released.html#toc_app-import-files-within-node_modules).  More details here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/7045